# ActiveMQ REST API URI?

Tags: rest, servlets, jms, activemq-classic

I'm having trouble getting an example running using the REST API with ActiveMQ 5.4.0. I've seen several different GET URIs.

The [documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/rest.html) refers to this URI: *http://localhost:8161/demo/message/<queue name>?type=queue*

Other sources refer to these URIs:

1. http://localhost:8161/queue/<queue name>
2. http://localhost:8161/demo/message/<queue name>

Which URI is correct? Is there some configuration that I've missed?

Thank you!

Comment: Please see this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706788/jersey-rest-web-service-with-activemq-middleware-integration
How to do this. Please help!!!! Thanks for your time.

Comment: I have already put the question on their forum. But there is no reply from any of the members. Here is the link - http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/ActiveMq-Integration-with-Jersey-Rest-Service-td4673941.html and Thanks for your reply and time.

Answer (score 6):

If you make use of the ActiveMQ [MessageServlet](http://fisheye6.atlassian.com/browse/activemq/tags/activemq-5.4.0/activemq-web/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/web/MessageServlet.java?r=985385), then the format for the REST URI is:

`http://localhost:8080/message/test?readTimeout=1000&type=queue`

There is a demo of this URI format shown in the [RestTest](http://fisheye6.atlassian.com/browse/activemq/trunk/activemq-web-demo/src/test/java/org/apache/activemq/web/RestTest.java?r=HEAD).

Bruce

Comment: Hi Bruce: I was not able to get your URI to work, but I did try this: http://localhost:8161/demo/message/FOO.BAR?readTimeout=1000&type=queue which works fine. How can I configure it to use the MessageServlet? Thanks for your time. John

Answer (score 3):

If you are using ActiveMQ 5.8 or higher you should use this URL instead:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/message/test?readTimeout=1000&type=queue
```